# Remove row from form with vanilla js

Tags: javascript, forms

I have a form I enter student info (name, email, address) and I was able to add a new row (made of three columns) using JS after I click a button. Every time a new row is created, three new columns are created with three input boxes each with its own element ID. So far so good. However, now I can't for the life of me figure out how to remove the last row that was added. Below is my code:

```
var student_ids = 0;

document.getElementById("studentCount").value = student_ids;

function anotherStudent(){
    document.getElementById("student_info").innerHTML += 
        
                "<div class='section colm colm4'>"+
                        "<input type='text' name='stud_name_" + student_ids + "'id='stud_name_" +student_ids+ "'class='gui-input' placeholder='Student name'>"+
                "</div><!-- end section -->" +

                "<div class='section colm colm4'>" +
                        "<input type='email' name='stud_email_" + student_ids + "'id='stud_email_" + student_ids + "'class='gui-input' placeholder='Email'>" +
                "</div><!-- end section -->" +
                
                "<div class='section colm colm4'>" +
                    "<input type='text' name='stud_address_" + student_ids + "'id='stud_address_" + student_ids + "'class='gui-input' placeholder='Address'>"+
                "</div><!-- end section -->" ;      

    student_ids = ++student_ids;
    document.getElementById("studentCount").value = student_ids ;
}


function removeStudent(){
    
    var x = document.getElementById('stud_name_'+student_ids);
    var y = document.getElementById('stud_email_'+student_ids);
    var z = document.getElementById('stud_address_'+student_ids);
    
    x.remove(); 
    y.remove();
    z.remove();

}
```

Comment: When and how are you calling `removeStudent()`? Note that right now your `student_ids` will *never* be equal to any current student because you're always increasing them after adding a student. E.g., You've added a student where `student_ids` is `3`, you're increasing it to `4` and trying to call `removeStudent()` will attempt to find items where the ID is `4` but those don't exist.

Comment: On a different note: `student_ids = ++student_ids;` is useless - either use `++student_ids` by itself or `student_ids = student_ids + 1;` Don't mix the two.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit:

You are not removing the divs, only the inputs themselves. You are also incrementing the `student_ids` global variable after you insert a row. This means that the `removeStudent()` function will always try to remove a non-existing row.

It would be better to pass the desired `student_ids` to `removeStudent()`, or manually de-increment the value.

In older environments (such as Explorer):

You cannot directly remove DOM elements from JavaScript. It's a bit unintuitive, but you have to go to the parent of that element and remove it from there:

```
var element = document.getElementById('stud_name_'+student_ids);
element.parentNode.removeChild(element);
```

Comment: @VLAZ You are right, I entirely mistook the problem in the question, and forgot that the current DOM standard does indeed allow direct element removal. Edited.

Comment: Thank you VLAZ and @bluevulture. That did it. I am now working on removing the divs because I had not noticed that before. Much appreciated!